# After Changing primary key of custom modules' model , does not saves data in db

Tags: module, database, model, save

I have made custom module for that I have to change tables primary key due to some reasons.I have updated it in `Model\Resource\Modelclass.php` file , flush cache including "Flush Cache Storage" of cache management.

But enable to save data in db.

It shows properly the saved module and its id by
1.)

```
$saved_obj = $model->save();
echo'<pre>';print_r($saved_obj->getData()); exit;
```

2.)

```
$insertid = $model->save()->getId();
echo'<pre>';print_r($insertid); //exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem's answer in comment's of below question
[Magento model->save() doesnt working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889433/magento-model-save-doesnt-working) by [OSdave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219986/osdave).

As i have changed the pk but my one is not auto incremental so i have to specify to the model resource's construct that
`$this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;`